# Server to server authentication using Azure AD

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization

Trying to implement server to server authentication between my APIs through azure AD.
First I am creating a token with following configuration

```
var oauthApi = RestService.For<IMidaApi>(
                    $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_settings.TenantId}",
                    new RefitSettings(new NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer())
                );
                var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
                    { "client_id", _settings.ClientId},
                    { "client_secret", _settings.SecretKey },
                    { "scope", "api://1d1d113c-4b3b-****-******-********/.default" },
                };
                var response = await oauthApi.GetTokenAsync(data);
```

After successfully created token, Attaching to HTTPClient and doing request to another API which accepts Bearer token.

During validation it fails.
I have added AzureAd section in appsettings with following values:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://sts.windows.net/",
    "Audience": "api://1d1d113c-4b3b-4a2e-****-***********",
    "ClientId": "1d1d113c-4b3b-4a2e-****-***********",
    "TenantId": "3be67c15-c670-43c3-****-***********"
  }
```

instance - after decoding jwt token i get the following for Issuer + tenant ID
Audience exactly the same from decoded token
Client and TenantId from AzureAd registered APP.

in startup provided this:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
```

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

is in correct order.
Controller which needs this authentication has [Authorize] attribute.

Anything I do I keep getting Unauthorized exception.

Attaching some of the azure AD app registration configuration

[image]

seems like everything is correct here.
Exposed API as following

[image]

And permissions:

[image: Permiessiongs]

What am I missing in this configuration?

Verified credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I created an Azure AD Application and added scopes:

[image]

Now, I added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

I generated **access token via Postman using Client Credentials** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://c0a52d3b-ec8a-4cce-a10e-d279axxxxxx/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the **scopes are not present in the access token**:

[image]

> **Note** that: For Client Credential Flow, you need to pass Application permissions. Delegated permissions are passed while generating access token via Authorization Code Flow.

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

I created **App roles** in the Azure AD Application:

[image]

Now, I added **Application API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token via Postman using Client Credentials** like below:

[image]

When I decoded the token, **roles are present in the access token** as below:

[image]

To resolve the error, try creating the App roles, grant Application API permissions and generate the token and check.